# Are there formal refutations of the Charvaka criticism of the Shraddha ceremony?

Tags: shraddha, charvaka

Their argument is stated as below:

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-sarva-darsana-samgraha/d/doc79745.html

> If the Śrāddha produces gratification to beings who are dead,
> Then here, too, in the case of travellers when they start, it is needless to give provisions for the journey.
> If beings in heaven are gratified by our offering the Śrāddha here,
> Then why not give the food down below to those who are standing on the housetop?

Comment: No, as the Charvaka school is an ancient philosophy no modern adherents. It was a nastika system

Comment: I haven't read any refutation of Cārvāka's stance on śrāddha.